# Format date time properly with laravel and carbon

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, format, php-carbon

I try to add date and time into my database but I have problems:

First: I create a form:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-md-6">

    {!! Form::label('roba_spremna','The cargo is ready:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('roba_spremna', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">

    {!! Form::label('auction_end','Auction close at:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('auction_end', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
</div>
</div>
```

After that I add bootstrap-datetimepicker (js library):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
                $(function () {
                    $('#roba_spremna, #auction_end').datetimepicker();
                });
            });
```

and at Article model I write:

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'body',
        'roba_spremna',
        'auction_end'
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'roba_spremna',
        'auction_end'
    ];

    public function setRobaSpremnaAttribute($date){
        $this->attributes['roba_spremna']= Carbon::createFromFormat(''m/d/Y h:i a', $date);
    }
```

Now When I try to store date with time at my database so when I submit form I get this error:

> InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425: Unexpected data
>   found. Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Trailing data

[image]
How I can solve my problem?

Comment: `Carbon::createFromFormat(''m/d/Y h:i a', $date);` should be `Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y h:i a', $date);`

Comment: ok, that was mistake here at StackOverflow code not at my real code... sorry

Comment: i think you should show you controller code where you process the form and pass the data to the model

Comment: `Carbon::createFromFormat(''m/d/Y h:i a', $date);` should be `Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y h:i A', $date);` @Moppo

Comment: sorry people the problem was becouse I dont add functiion setAuctionEndAttribute ... I will delete this question

Comment: Keep it, maybe someone else will have the problem. Just write what the problem was and how you solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to solves this is to debug your controller or use the dd() function.
Anyway your goal is to see what exactly your date looks like while you're in the controller.

Depends if you inject the request as a parameter in the controller function or use the facade dd call should looks like this :

```
dd($request->get('roba_spremna'));
```

or via the facade :

```
dd(\Request::get('roba_spremna'));
```

Then you need to compare the date format with your mask.
Ultimately copy the date you got from dd(), then launch

```
php artisan tinker
```

create a variable containing the date as a string 
and try to create manually a carbon object with it to see what mask you really need.